# R Comparing two lists for exact equality

Tags: r, list

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = list(2, 3, 5)
list_2 = list(2, 3, 5)
```

How can I find out if the 2 lists are exactly equal. It can be done in hard way too, but is there a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just for this task is the function `identical()`

```
list_1 = list(2, 3, 5)
list_2 = list(2, 3, 5)
identical(list_1, list_2)
# [1] TRUE
```

but

```
list_1 = list(2, 3, 5)
list_2 = list(2, 5, 3)
identical(list_1, list_2)
# [1] FALSE
```

and

```
list_1 = list(2, 3, 5)
list_2 = list(2, 3L, 5)
identical(list_1, list_2)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

```
identical(list_1,list_2)
```

should work.